# Flutter - Get Product details connect an API to UI using GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am flutter beginner, using dart language. I am trying to integrate an API with UI in Flutter using GetX.
I created Json class and product controls. When I try to create the product list view, I get the below errors.

Thanks in advance!

Error lines:

```
1. itemCount: productController.productList.length,
2. productController.productList[index].imageLink,
3. productController.productList[index].title,
```

Errors:

1. The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Rx'.
2. The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Rx'.
3. The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Rx'.

Product List Code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:practice/commonmodule/AppColor.dart';
    import 'package:practice/commonmodule/AppString.dart';
    import 'package:practice/productmodule/controllers/product_controller.dart';
    import 'package:get/get.dart';

    class ProductListView extends StatelessWidget {
     final ProductController productController = Get.put(ProductController());

     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(AppString.productList),
      ),
      body: Obx(
        () {
          if (productController.isLoading.value)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          else
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: productController.productList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 150,
                          height: 100,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 8, 8),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            child: Image.network(
                              productController.productList[index].imageLink,
                              width: 150,
                              height: 100,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              color: AppColor.bluecolor,
                              colorBlendMode: BlendMode.color,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                            child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              productController.productList[index].title,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              productController.productList[index].description,
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: AppColor.grey),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              productController.productList[index].price,
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: AppColor.grey),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: AppColor.grey200,
                      height: 2,
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
        },
      ),
    );
    }
    }
```

Product controller code:

```
class ProductController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var productList = ProductModel().obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchProducts();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchProducts() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var products = await ApiService.fetchProducts();
      if (products != null) {
        productList.value = products;
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

`

Comment: can you also put the productlist sample data i think this is just data model error only which you only getting 1 data not a list

Comment: in the UI file you should use `productController.productList.value` instead of `productController.productList`.

Comment: @ArbiterChil -  Thanks for your response. Yes, for now I need to get only one data.

Comment: @HarshSureja - Thanks! I also tried with 'value'. But the error remains. 1.productController.productList.value.length
2. productController.productList.value[index].imageLink
3. productController.productList.value[index].title

Answer (score 0):

You need to create ProductList Model To List Model.

```
class ProductController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  RxList[ProductModel]  productList= [].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchProducts();
    super.onInit();
   }

   void fetchProducts() async {
   try {
    isLoading(true);
    var products = await ApiService.fetchProducts();
    if (products != null) {
    productList.value = products;
    }
  } finally {
    isLoading(false);
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ProductListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final ProductController productController = Get.put(ProductController());
  ProductListView({super.key});

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('productList'),
  ),
  body: Obx(
    () {
      if (productController.isLoading.value) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      } else {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: productController.productList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 150,
                      height: 100,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 8, 8),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          productController.productList[index].imageLink,
                          width: 150,
                          height: 100,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          colorBlendMode: BlendMode.color,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          productController.productList[index].title,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          productController.productList[index].description,
                          style:
                              const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          productController.productList[index].price.toString(),
                          style:
                              const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                  height: 2,
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    },
  ),
);
}
}

class ProductController extends GetxController {
  final isLoading = true.obs;
  RxList<ProductModel> productList= <ProductModel>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchProducts();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchProducts() async {
    try {
      isLoading.value = true;
      List<ProductModel> products = await ApiService().fetchProducts();
      if (products.isNotEmpty) {
        productList.value = products;
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }
}
class ProductModel {
  int? id;
  String title;
  String description;
  int price;
  String imageLink;
  ProductModel({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageLink,
  });
  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) => ProductModel(
    title: data["title"],
    description: data["description"],
    price: data["price"] ,
    imageLink: data["imageLink"],
  );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(data) => {
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "price": price,
        "imageLink": imageLink,
  };
}
class ApiService {
  Future<List<ProductModel>> fetchProducts() async {
    String json = '''[{
      "title": "title1",
      "description": "description1",
      "price": 1,
      "imageLink": "images/ic_facebook.png"
    }, {
      "title": "title2",
      "description": "description2",
      "price": 2,
      "imageLink": "images/ic_google.png"
    },{
      "title": "title3",
      "description": "description3",
      "price": 3,
      "imageLink": "images/ic_home_filled.png"
    }]''';

  var plistJson = jsonDecode(json) as List;
  List<ProductModel> plist = plistJson.map((tagJson) => ProductModel.fromJson(tagJson)).toList();
  return plist;
  }
}
```

**screenshot**

[image]