# How can I read Data from a JSON File and display it in Flutter Widgets?

Tags: ios, json, flutter

I would like to use my JSON file to store all the info in it to display in Flutter.
Everytime i get this Error:
`_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>')`

Here are my Files:
[db.json](https://codeshare.io/nzopbX)
[breed_page.dart](https://codeshare.io/LwEMmb)

Can someone help me solving this error or show me a better way to do this?

Normally, the name and image should be read from the JSON file and then displayed in the list tile as a circle image or as text. I have also checked my JSON file and tried other functions like this one but nothing helped. By the way I am a newbie in Flutter

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: breeds.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Image.network(breeds[index]['img']),
      title: Text(breeds[index]['name']),
      onTap: () {
        // TODO: Navigate to breed details page
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: see this answer it helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75623555/flutter-get-product-details-connect-an-api-to-ui-using-getx/75629775#75629775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your decoded json string is `Map<String,dynamic>` not a `List<dynamic>`

```
{
    "breeds":[
       {
```

the `List` are a value from key `breeds`

Workaroud:

```
  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchBreeds() async {
    String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('lib/db.json');
   final tempDecoded = json.decode(jsonString);
   // now get the list with key breeds
   final breeds = tempDecoded["breeds"];
    return breeds;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

`json.decode(jsonString);` seems to be converting the data from `String` to `Map<String, dynamic>` instead of `List<dynamic>`

Please go through the language docs to check if you're using the right return type for your json
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.3/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html